# How to properly use bootstrap push and pull

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been trying to re-order my bootstrap columns when in mobile view but my code is just not working. Most probably because I am doing something incorrect.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2 class="mb-lg-4 mb-sm-3">Early Stages</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-push-5">
            <p>Also known as &apos;the Poor Fellow-Soldiers of Christ and of the Temple of Solomon&apos;, the Knights Templars were originally founded circa 1120 CE, by Hugues de Payens, as a means to protect Christian pilgrims to the Holy Land. It was originally intended that nine Templars would protect the pilgrims.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-push-7">
            Image Here
        </div>
    </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is essentially make the "Image Here" section go above the "also known as the poor etc." section when in mobile view (col-sm). I looked at Bootstraps guide but I think I am understanding it incorrectly, can someone show me how its done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: on large screens you need image on right or left

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2 class="mb-lg-4 mb-sm-3">Early Stages</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-push-7">
      Image Here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-pull-5">
      <p>Also known as &apos;the Poor Fellow-Soldiers of Christ and of the Temple of Solomon&apos;, the Knights Templars were originally founded circa 1120 CE, by Hugues de Payens, as a means to protect Christian pilgrims to the Holy Land. It was originally
        intended that nine Templars would protect the pilgrims.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/w2s617a9/6/)

hope this helps..

Comment: Hey Chandra, this works! Do you think you can explain the logic behind this solution?

Comment: Actually sorry, when I put in your code on my page, the "Image here" is showing up on the left side on desktop view, when I wanted it to be on the right side, but on mobile view at the top. But it's odd because when I clicked your reference link, the "Image here" is on the right

Comment: is this the HTML what you need?